# After selecting items in the Spinner, it is not getting reflected to me (not visible to naked eye)

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

I am working on a project in which I need to dynamically add `TextView` and `Spinner` as well. I was able to add these two things dynamically from my program successfully.

Now when I was trying to select some items in the Spinner, that items is not getting shown in my emulator but the items that I selected gets shown in the Toast.

Does I need to do anything to make that item selected in `Spinner`?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapColumns.entrySet()) {

    spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(cont);
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(cont);

    rowTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for(String s: entry.getValue().split(",")) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");

        spinnerArray.add(s);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(cont, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

    rowTextView.setText(entry.getKey());
    rowTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    // add the listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    layout.addView(rowTextView);
    layout.addView(spinner);
}

class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener : "
                + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Below is my XML Layout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/llayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Save" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Here `mapColumns` will hev Key-Value pair. So in the Spinner all the items are getting shown from the Value of that map.

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I need to make sure if anybody is selecting any items in the Spinner, it should get selected and be visible to other person.

Below is the image in which I have selected items in the `Spinner` but it is not getting shown and also `TextView` is also very light in color-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code which you are using to populate the spinnerArray looks suspicious because it will remove all the characters from the string.

```
for(String s: entry.getValue().split(",")) {
    ///System.out.println(s); move this print statement to below line and see what it prints in your logs
    s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
     System.out.println(s);

    spinnerArray.add(s);
}
```

So if the spinnerArray is provided with empty string it will come up with empty spinner. I would suggest comment out the whole block and then try your app and see if the problem persist.

If you want the spinner to comeup with a selected item then add the following line:

```
  spinner.setSelection (0);
```

Comment: No, that's not a problem. I tested it out. As I said in my question. Toast is showing me the items that I have selected. I am attaching another image which will make things clear.

Comment: setSelection (int position) method i think you need to use if you want the spinner to display an initial item selected. I assume you can see list of the items once you click on the spinner?

Comment: I was scrolling down my cursor and then I can see my items selected in each spinner.

Comment: How can I get the index in my case? Can you provide me the exact code that I can use here? As I am confuse here where should I put this line and how to get the index.

Comment: I have already edited my answer to reflect the spinner.setSelection(0)  try selecting 0 for the first one

Comment: Where should I add this line in my code? Just below this line- `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`?

Comment: @TechGeeky I would be happy to know if this has helped? many thanks

Comment: Yup. It helped a lot. Thanks